# Android write problems PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, android, kivy, exif

I wrote a script that updates exif data of the WhatsApp images. I wanted to run it on my Android phone using Pydroid app, however I end up with the PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied error.

```
import os
import piexif
import datetime

dir_path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images'

img_count = 1
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
  for fname in files:
      if fname.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif')):
        img_path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        exif_dict = piexif.load(img_path)
        if not exif_dict['Exif'].get(piexif.ExifIFD.DateTimeOriginal, ""):
          mtime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(img_path)).strftime("%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")
          exif_dict['Exif'][piexif.ExifIFD.DateTimeOriginal] = mtime
          exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
          piexif.insert(exif_bytes, img_path)
          print(f"[{img_count}] DateTimeOriginal of {img_path} updated successfully to {mtime}")
          img_count += 1
```

I found that some of the people recommend adding these lines to the code in order to request write permissions:

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    
request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ...])
```

However I am ending up with another issues:

```
Error importing module "android": this module is a part of Kivy
You cannot use it from elsewhere and you barely need it at all
This is not a bug, please do not report it via email or Google Play reviews, thank you for your understanding
```

Is there any other option to grant WRITE permissions on Android? Or any other solution on performing a batch exif data update on Android files?
I am familiar with Java as well, so I could possibly try with that if I'm Python it's not possible.

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp is private storage for whatsapp app. Your app has no access to other apps private storage. You cannot even list the files. Why did not you tell so?

Comment: The problem is that for some reason WhatsApp had 2 folders on my phone and backup was duplicating my images with the current date. I wanted to change the date to the original date that is visible on my PC. I am able to edit exif data for the images on my PC using this script, but when I copy these correct images to the WhatsApp folder all exif data is removed from the images and date is updated for the current timestamp.

Comment: `but when I copy these correct images to the WhatsApp folder ` How exactly are you doing that?

Comment: I copy all the files to PC where I can see the original date in the details, but gallery on my phone does not see that. So I run the script, move these files to the phone memory storage and from there I copy all the files to the WhatsApp folder directly where exif data gets removed and only current date time remains.

Comment: `I copy all the files to PC` Already here we do not know what you do. Where are those files? And how do you copy them? Please step by step.

Comment: 1. Go to phone's file manager.
2. Copy all images from the WhatsApp folder to any other arbitrary one.
3. Using USB send these files to PC.
4. Run the script to update EXIF data for these images.
5. Send files back to the arbitrary folder onto phone's storage via USB. 
6. Copy corrected files directly into WhatsApp folder using phone's file manager.
7. Files in the WhatsApp folder revert changes done to EXIF data.

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong you are talking about media subfolder with storage/emulated/0/Android/media/ and indeed apps have acces. I have to rethink.

Comment: About 7. How do you know that exif changed? Is it done by Whatsapp or during copy by file manager? How are you inspecting?

Comment: Just copied a jpg file from DCIM/Camera folder to ...Android/media/com.com.com. No changes in exif info. I dont know how you inspect or where you loose the exif.

Comment: All apps can read media files of other apps in media folder. But they can not write files of other apps unless 'all files access'. Thats it.

Comment: @blackapps I firstly check the file from the arbitrary folder - my updated exif is there. But when I copy the same image to the WhatsApp folder and inspect it there - the only exif tag that is there is the last modified time which is overridden by current timestamp. And yes - READ operation works without issues, I can read the EXIF tags but on the insert (WRITE) operation, I get the PermissionError

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to access private files from another application. For this to occur, that application must utilize a `FileProvider`, or it might be possible to share data through a `ContentProvider`. Otherwise, access is not possible. Given the sensitivity of such data, it can be concluded that WhatsApp does not offer this capability.

[Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#filesInternal)

[Sharing files](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html)

[Content provider basics](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics)